# Is there any significant draw backs on recursive struct list?

Tags: c++, struct, template-meta-programming

My question is for a struct like below, is it hard on the memory?
Should I avoid such struct? It feels legit but seems to deviate from "normal" c++ patterns.

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct Cons {};
```

...

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct head<Cons<a, b>> { using type = a; };
```

...

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct tail<Cons<a, b>> { using type = b; };
```

...

```
template<typename list>
struct recursive_list
{
    using head = typename head<list>::type;
    using tail = typename tail<list>::type;

    head curr;
    recursive_list<tail> next;
};
```

...

```
recursive_list<Cons<int,Cons<std::string,Nil>>> rl;
rl.curr=1;
rl.next.curr="2";
```

Comment: I assume you also have a `struct Nil{};` you aren't showing? I *think* that should be fine and might even be a common way to implement `std::tuple`.

Comment: @DanielH yeah, I thought that was trivial so I didn't put it there. It just feels weird c++ handles this matryoshka doll of a struct.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it, it should not cause any issues. That is, the memory consumed would be the same as if you'd declared a struct with all the fields from the `Cons` pairs together. There's alignment issues to take into consideration, which might be exacerbated depending on how good the compiler is. I'm thinking here of the structure being bigger because fields can't be packed more closely because they belong to different types. But that shouldn't be an issue unless you're explicitly asking for this sort of packing.

One thing to take into consideration is `vtables`. If you want to add virtual functions, you might need to pay the cost of one vtable entry for each `Cons` (which basically means for each field).

Comment: So if say I have 8 elements in the list, the size will actually increase at least 32 if virtual methods are present? Good to know.

Comment: It should still be "8" elements (and however many bytes that is), provided you don't use virtual functions. If you do, you'll add 8 pointers to that size (or 64 bytes in total).